# How to make support the HTML tag "oembed" by the wordpress editor

Tags: html, wordpress, tags, editor, oembed

I want to add the following html code to my wordpress editor but the youtube video is not embeded. The url disappear.

`<figure><oembed url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=btDyQlFQCew"></oembed></figure>`

How to make the wordpress editor accept the "oembed" html tag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the native WordPress `Embed Block`:
https://wordpress.org/support/article/embeds/

And in general you can just paste the link itself (URL only) inside the WordPress editor and it will automatically generate the embed for you.